# How can I create a ManagementScope for a Mail-enabled security group?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

I am working with the office365 online exchange and mostly powershell.

I would like to create a write scope for a admin role group so that one mail enabled security group is able to manage only a specific other Mail-enabled security group.

I found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351083(v=exchg.150).aspx). But I am not sure how I can select a Mail-enabled security group as scope.

Comment: Is creation of custom scope as explained here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351083(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_1 not helping with your situation.

Comment: I cant find any example on security groups there, only users or servers.